# How to copy the Current Sheet to the multiple Sheets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

**Greetings**

*Sorry about my english I have a lack of insight of my english well !*




**My Question is**

*How to copy the Current Sheet to the multiple Sheets in the Google Sheets ?*




**My Achievements are**

I try find the code to looking for this case what I've found it is in this [link](http://igoogledrive.blogspot.co.id/2012/10/Google-Spreadsheet-Script-to-Copy-Sheet-to-multiple-Spreadsheets-at-a-time.html)




**My Problem now it hasn't solve is**

When I'm trying to execute the script the copies are an acomplished run but there is have an one a problem that is which the copied by the script is not exactly the current Sheet but always the first Sheet everytime I run the script. What is the problem whereas I've trying to change these line ;


`var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().***;`


*To be*

`var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().***;`


*Or*

`var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().***;`


*Or*

`var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActive().***;`

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("name of the sheet")`?

Comment: No Thare is no tag name of getCurrentSpreadsheet in Google Spreadsheet if I've might not wrong.

Comment: Anyone could help ? Can someone help me to solve this problem (for copy the current sheet to multiple spreadsheets ?

Comment: If you run the script from the script interface or from a trigger, the currently sheet will always be the 1st one. Ether get the sheet with it&#39;s name or call the function from it

Comment: to @LioraHaydont. Could you please tell me how or How to write this to become something what you have suggest to me about the completely code that have fixed these bugs.